# AHK script localization

Tags: c#, shell, autohotkey

I'm writing C# library and I'm using AHK to display text on screen (together with some other AHK features), however I want this text to be localized to different locales. How this can be achieved? I tried to search AHK documentation and forums, but could not find anything. Is this impossible or is there any trick?

I'm using this to render the text:

```
Gui, Add, Text, "Text to be localized"
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I want this text to be localized to different locales" ?? I dont understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you please give us an example to clarify the question?

Comment: @freestock.tk I mean to have it in different languages based on the PC's locale - if set to Spain, for example, I want the text to be in Spanish (same as .NET framework works). I will provide the different translations, I just want to know how to make AHK select the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use the built-in variable %A_Language%

[-Click here to see the List of the Language Codes-](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Languages.htm)

Usage Example:

```
if A_Language in 0416,0816
{
text:="Olá"
}

else if A_Language in 040a,080a,0c0a,100a,140a,180a,1c0a,200a,240a,280a,2c0a,300a,340a,380a,3c0a,400a,440a,480a,4c0a,500a
{
text:="Holla"
}

else
{
text:="Hello"
}

Gui, Add, Text, %text%
```

Comment: In addition to that, there seems to be a nifty [i18n library](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/50131-simple-internationalization-function/) for storing translations in a useful format and accessing them easily.